# compare and show data that does not match

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter, join

How would I alter my query to select all data that is done not share `ReportID` ?

So all `'report.Report_Name, report.ReportDate, report.ReportID'`
that does not match `report.ReportID = Read_Report.ReportID`

and then get all that does not match from `report`

**Query**

```
 $this->db->select('report.Report_Name, report.ReportDate, report.ReportID')
            ->from('report')
            ->join('Read_Report', 'report.ReportID = Read_Report.ReportID')
            ->where('Read_Report.StaffID', $this->session->userdata("StaffID"));
        $result = $this->db->get();
        return $result->result();
```

Comment: In which code you are translating sql ?

Comment: sorry, im using codeigniter

Comment: since it's a select statement can you just send raw sql?

Comment: Sorry @SamOrozco how do you mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is a difference between two sets, usually this is done with a left join and a null where clause on the foreign key of the right table (some database provide an intersect functionnality but since I don't know which database you use I will stick to what will work on any flavors of SQL)

So your query should be like this :

```
SELECT report.Report_name, report.ReportDate, report.ReportId
FROM report LEFT JOIN Read_Report ON report.ReportId=Read_Report.ReportId
WHERE Read_Report.ReportId IS NULL
```

I don't know the specific syntax of your querybuilder but I think you will have a leftJoin method and a way to check if a column is null.

By the way, try to stick to a unique naming and case scheme for your tables and columns names

Comment: Thanks dude, Il give this a fiddel. see it i can get it working. i guess il still need `$this->session->userdata("StaffID")` to show data percific to my user

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will work?

```
    $this->db->select('report.Report_Name, report.ReportDate, report.ReportID')
        ->from('report')
        ->join('Read_Report', 'report.ReportID = Read_Report.ReportID')
        ->where('Read_Report.StaffID !=', $this->session->userdata("StaffID"));
    $result = $this->db->get();
    return $result->result();
```